# Get text with Xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I want to collect GitHub users' monthly contributions from 2004 until now as shown in the picture. [image]  And output the monthly data into csv file with corresponding month columns (e.g., 2022_10). The Xpath of these texts is:

```
#//*[@id="js-contribution-activity"]/div/div/div/div/details/summary/span[1]
```

This is what my csv file (df1) looks like:

|  | LinkedIn Website | GitHub Website | user |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | https://www.linkedin.com/in/chad-roberts-b86699/ | https://github.com/crobby | crobby |
| 1 | https://www.linkedin.com/in/grahamdumpleton/ | https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton | GrahamDumpleton |

Here is my best try so far:

```
for index, row in df1.iterrows():
    try:
        user = row['user']
    except:
        pass
    for y in range(2004, 2023):
        for m in range(1, 13):
            try:
                current_url = f'https://github.com/{user}?tab=overview&from={y}-{m}-01&to={y}-{m}-31'
                print(current_url)
                driver.get(current_url)
                time.sleep(0.1)
                contribution = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.xpath("//*[@id='js-contribution-activity']/div/div/div/div/details/summary/span[1]")).getText();
                df1.loc[index, f'{str(y)}_{str(m)}'] = contribution
            except:
                pass

print(df1)
df1.to_csv('C:/Users/fredr/Desktop/output today.csv')
```

I cannot figure out why there is no output. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `WebDriverWait` `expected_conditions` explicit waits.
I see there are multiple `contribution` fields there, so you need to collect all those elements as a list and then to iterate over the list extracting each element text.
You need to improve your locators, they should be short and clear as possible.
Also you mixed in your code Java and Python. `getText()` and `;` are from Java...
Try this:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)

driver.get(current_url)
contributions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//*[@id='js-contribution-activity']//summary/span[1]")))
for contribution in contributions:
    print(contribution.text)
```

Comment: May I ask a follow-up question? @Prophet I'm trying to collect the list of contributions in single cells of a data frame, month by month. It gives me the bug: ValueError: "Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an iterable." Could you please help me out? I update the code in my question since it is too long to send in a comment. Thanks again!

Comment: It will be much better to open a **new** question for that. Stackoverflow rules say each question should be narrowed to a specific issue. Also, when you ask a new question it appears on the top of the feed of incoming questions. Especially since this question is marked as resolved most people will not open it since it is resolved.

Comment: Thank you for introducing the society rule to me, @Prophet. I'll open a new question now.

Comment: You are welcome again and always :)

Comment: Hi, @Prophet, here is my follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74338944/output-list-of-text-into-single-cell-of-dataframe

Comment: Yah, I see it. Again, at least currently I'm not sure I know how to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried it with selenium but with just `requests` and `lxml` this xpath expression

```
//div[@class="contribution-activity-listing float-left col-12 "]//details[@class="Details-element details-reset"]/summary/span[1]
```

seems to work.